# JSONB Represent jsonb key value like array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have field `extra` with type `jsonb` in my table `product`. And I need get uniq key with uniq values for each key from all products row. Example data in extra field

```
{"SIZE": "110/116", "COLOUR": "Vit", "GENDER": "female", "AGE_GROUP": "Kids", "ALTERNATIVE_IMAGE": "some_path"}
```

for now I use query like this

```
        select DISTINCT e.key, array_agg(DISTINCT e.value) as fields 
        from products AS p 
        join jsonb_each_text(p.extras) e on true        
        GROUP BY e.key
```

Ad have respnse (small part with some keys in full response all keys are present) like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "AGE_GROUP",
    "fields": "{Adult,children,Kids}"
  },
  {
    "key": "GENDER",
    "fields": "{female,male,man}"
  }
]
```

how to change it to array for fields alias ?

like this

```
[
  {
    "AGE_GROUP": ["Adult","children","Kids"]
  },
  {
    "GENDER": ["female","male","man"]
  }
]
```

or maybe whould be great like this

```
[
"some_alias": [{"AGE_GROUP": "Adult", "AGE_GROUP": "children", "AGE_GROUP": "Kids"}],
"some_alias": [{"GENDER": "female", "GENDER": "male", "GENDER": "man"}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the former form I think:

```
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(k,v)) from (
        select DISTINCT e.key, jsonb_agg(DISTINCT e.value) as fields 
        from products AS p 
        join jsonb_each_text(p.extras) e on true        
        GROUP BY e.key
) b(k,v);
```

Best regards,
Bjarni